# Is there any statistical basis to relative error?

Tags: error, intuition

Given a true value $b$ and an approximated value $a$, Wikipedia defines the *absolute error* to be $\lvert a-b \rvert$ and the *relative error* $\left\lvert\frac{a-b}{b}\right\rvert$.

Ensuring that the absolute error is less than $x$ is similar to ensuring that the KL divergence between standard Gaussians having means $b$ and $a$ is less than $\frac{x^2}2$.

Can a similar statement be made for the relative error?

At first I thought it might be an exponential distribution KL divergence, but that is

$$\frac{a-b}{b} + \log \frac{b}{a}.$$

Does the relative error have any statistical meaning or is it merely heuristic?

Comment: Relative error is important for some cost functions. When you optimize the predictor you need a cost function.

Comment: @Aksakal:  Sure, but what does it **mean**?  In other words, why not use exponential distribution KL divergence as your cost function, which has a clear meaning?

Comment: Prior to the question, it doesn't make much sense to leave the denominator out of the absolute value, in the definition of relative error.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Good point, fixed.